# resolving sys.path in test

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

My code structure is following:

```
<root>
+-- src
|    +- module1.py
|    |
|    +- module2.py
|    |
|    + __init__.py
|
+-- test
     +- test1
     |    +- test1.py
     |    |
     |    + __init__.py
     |
     +- test2.py
     |
     +- __init__.py
```

`test/__init__.py` contains following:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(".")
```

and `test/test1/__init__.py` contains following:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("..")
```

Both `test1.py` and `test2.py` contains `from src import module1, module2`

When I run `pytest test1`, it works fine but when I run just `pytest`, the test2 fails with the import statement as it could not resolve `src`

I've tried modifying `test/__init__.py` to append ".." to the sys.path - it does not help.

Also, I have tried the import statement as `from ..src import module1, module2` - it does not work either.

What is the way to resolve sys.path in this case?

Answer (score 2):

My experience told me not to fix up the `sys.path` inside the tests: The should not care about that. It is better to control `sys.path` outside of these tests. Here is one way to do that. I will keep the same file structure, then

1. Delete all `__init__.py` files in the test dir

   ```
    find test -name __init__.py -delete
   ```
2. Issue `pytest` command:

   ```
    PYTHONPATH=. pytest
   ```

This way, your file structure is much simpler. The tests don't care where the module are, they just import them.

An alternative is to install the [python-path](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-pythonpath/) plug-in, which manages your PYTHONPATH for the tests.